# Disable cleanup/purging of crash reports

Tags: macos, crash, logs

From the man page:

```
SubmitDiagInfo also cleans up any diagnostic and usage information which was created more than one month ago and is no longer needed.
```

How can I disable this behavior or set a longer expiration duration?

The crash reports I'm mentioning are in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` and `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`.

Comment: You could back the files up to another folder with a daily script and let macOS do its thing when it wants to. This folder could be on any drive connected to your Mac, local network, or even to the cloud somewhere.